# Playing videos with LibGDX

Tags: android, video, libgdx

First of all, I know that playing videos is considered "out of scope" for LibGDX.

I've been working on an Android App that allows you to record videos and play them, everything from "inside" LibGDX using Android Camera API.
I've managed to get the recording part working, more or less (on some old devices like Galaxy Ace the screen does weird things instead of recording),
but i'm stuck with the "Playing the video that I've just recorded" part.
I know it's easy calling an Intent and using system's Media Player to do the job,

```
     Intent intent = new Intent();              
     intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);               
     intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myvideo.mp4"), "video/*");
             ...
     activity.startActivity(intent);
```

but that it's not a decent solution since it's not really "responsive"(I lose control when the user is inside the Intent).
So my question is, is it possible to use Android MediaPlayer API with LibGDX at the same time to play a video?
I've tryed and didn't get any result, most times I've got "start failed() -9" errors or no errors but the screen wouldn't show anything.
This is some of the code i've used:

Inside Android:

```
public void startPlaying(){     
    if (player.getCurrentPosition() == 0){
        try{        
            player.setDisplay(holder);              
            player.setDataSource(path);
            player.prepare();
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    player.start();
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "Playing Started");
}
```

While we're playing the video in LibGDX we're just clearing the screen and nothing else:

```
    GLCommon gl = Gdx.gl20;
    gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE);                     
    gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);     
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL20.GL_LEQUAL);
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0F);
```

Comment: I think it can do. use MediaPlay API to play video and use libgdx to show OSD ui control. if that, the only method(I know) is call initializeForView .

Comment: Could you do something really low level, like read the media file, and load the pixels in each frame to a texture that then gets rendered with OpenGL? I don't know much about media playback specifically though, so feel free to tear that idea apart :D